# Core Data Save Managed Object Context - error pointer is nil

Tags: objective-c, core-data, pointers

I'm getting an error on a when saving changes to the managed object context, but I have a problem with my error handler: the error is nil, and thus gives me no useful information. I have two versions of the error handler. This one was generated by Xcode, and it works (i.e., the log message contains useful error info):

AppDelegate.c

```
- (void)saveContext
{
NSError *error = nil;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
if (managedObjectContext != nil)
{
    if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    } 
}
}
```

But I want to be able to pass success/failure (eventually, for now I'm just aborting) + the error information back to the caller, so I have this, which does not work (error is nil, and so provides no useful information about the error).

Database.h

```
+ (BOOL) commit:(NSError **)error;
```

Database.c

```
+ (BOOL) commit:(NSError **)error {


AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

if (managedObjectContext != nil)
{
    if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:error])
    {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
         */
        if (error == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error");
            abort();
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", *error, [*error userInfo]);
            abort();
            //return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
return FALSE;
}
```

I'm pretty sure my problem is with the pointers, and getting lost in the layers of redirection.

[EDIT:]
The code that calls commit:

```
[Database commit:nil];
```

I wonder if I need to add something like this to the start of the commit method, but I'm not sure about the pointers:

```
if (error == nil) {
    error = [[NSError alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: 1) Does the save operation actually fail? If it succeeds, `error` is not set to anything. - 2) Can you show us how the `commit:` method is called? - 3) The above code aborts in the error case and therefore cannot return an error.

Comment: @MartinR 1) Yes, it fails. 2) The commit is called passing in a nil... hm... I wonder if this is the problem. 3) The code does abort (for now), but it also logs an error. My problem is that the error I'm getting is the first one (just "Unresolved error") instead of the second one (with error info), because error = nil (also confirmed error = nil via the debugger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `commit:` is called with `nil` (from your comment) then this is probably the error. You have to call your function with the address of an error variable:

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![Database commit:&error]) {
    // commit failed, "error" contains error message.
}
```

and of course `return NO` instead of `abort()` in the error case inside the `commit` method.

There is no need to allocate the error message in your `commit` method. `[managedObjectContext save:error]` will do that if the save fails.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass the address of error in that second version no?

```
[managedObjectContext save:error]
```

should be:

```
[managedObjectContext save:&error]
```

This allows the receiving method to control what the pointer (that the pointer is pointing to) is referencing.